# Xpath or operator. How to use

Tags: xpath, operators

I did not get exactly how to use an or operator within an Xpath.

Let's assume i have a xml of thi structure:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b/>
        <c/>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b/>
    </a>
    <a>
        <d/>
        <b/>
    </a>
    <a>
        <d/>
        <c/>
    </a>
</root>
```

can i get with a single Xpath all the A node wich have as soon a node B or C.
I know i could look for the B and the see in a separate way and after sum the result removing repetition (as shown below) but i am sure there is a better way.

```
List1 = Xpath(./a/b/..)
List2 = Xpath(./a/c/..)
MyResult = (List1 + List2 - Repetitions)
```

I guess the solution could then apply as well for the AND operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/root/a[b or c]` will give you all `<a>` elements that have either a `<b>` or `<c>` child.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;

namespace XpathOp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
                <root>
                    <a>
                        <b/>
                        <c/>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        <b/>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        <d/>
                        <b/>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                        <d/>
                        <c/>
                    </a>
                </root>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//a[b or c]"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Founde node, name: {0}, hash: {1}", node.Name, node.GetHashCode());
            }

            XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));

            XPathNavigator navi = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator nodeIter = navi.Select("//a[b or c]");

            foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodeIter)
            {
                IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = node as IXmlLineInfo;
                Console.WriteLine("Found at line {0}, position {1}", lineInfo.LineNumber, lineInfo.LinePosition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found node, name: a, hash: 62476613
Found node, name: a, hash: 11404313
Found node, name: a, hash: 64923656
Found node, name: a, hash: 44624228
Found at line 3, position 26
Found at line 7, position 26
Found at line 10, position 26
Found at line 14, position 26
```